# Animated pipe (Canvas, JavaScript or CSS3)

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I'm looking for a framework that allows you to make a Subway map or that renders pipes. But I would like to animate it in the sense that you can see 'traffic' on the lines.

My idea is to create a visual monitoring system for message queues.

I found this "London Underground" jQuery plugin, but it's not animated: http://kalyani.com/2010/10/subway-map-visualization-jquery-plugin/

**Does anyone know of such a framework that already exists?** If not, what is the best solution to make this? Canvas, JS, CSS3 or some kind of hybrid?

Comment: Do the individual "pipes" or segments of "pipes" need to be independently animated? Do you need more complex representation than multiple cases of from origin to destination, in other words representing a network of nodes?

Comment: Frameworks are always generic so I think there will be none. The plugin you posted can be customized.. maybe you can dig in the code and write your own animate code instead of the colors.

Comment: Yes, animation between nodes are needed. And a pipe can have multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **D3.js..**

D3.js is a **JavaScript library** for manipulating documents based on data. D3 helps you bring data to life using **HTML, SVG and CSS**. D3’s emphasis on web standards gives you the full capabilities of modern browsers without tying yourself to a proprietary framework, combining powerful visualization components and a data-driven approach to DOM manipulation.

http://d3js.org/

Some good examples are here: (Node based)
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Thanks. Already searched for D3.js, but never found that Gallery link. Unfortunately they don't have anything that I need, so I guess I have to roll my own. D3.js looks good!

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but I did look at D3 and it appears to be the right tool for the job. So accepted the answer.